# Limit of divided differences.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods, interpolation

> I'm trying to show that the limit of Newton's interpolation formula as $x_i\to x_0$ ($i=1,\ldots,n$) gives the Taylor's formula (knowing that $f\in \mathcal{C}^{n+1}[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$)
>   $$T(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\ldots+\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}$$
>   The Newton's interpolation formula is
>   $$P_n(x)=f(x_0)+f(x_0,x_1)(x-x_0)+\ldots+f(x_0,\ldots,x_n)(x-x_0)\ldots (x-x_{n-1})$$
>   So basically I must show that
>   $$\lim_{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\to(x_0,\ldots,x_0)}P_n(x)=T(x)$$

$f(x_0,\ldots,x_k)$ is defined as
$$f(x_0,\ldots,x_k)=\frac{f(x_1,\ldots,x_k)-f(x_0,\ldots,x_{k-1})}{x_k-x_0}$$
From that definition it's easy to show that
$$\lim_{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\to(x_0,\ldots,x_0)}f(x_0,x_1)=\lim_{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\to(x_0,\ldots,x_0)}\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}\overset{def}{=}f'(x_0)$$
But I get stuck when I have to find the limit of $f(x_0,x_1,x_2)$.
$$\lim_{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\to(x_0,\ldots,x_0)}f(x_0,x_1,x_2)=\lim_{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\to(x_0,\ldots,x_0)}\frac{f(x_1,x_2)-f(x_0,x_1)}{x_2-x_0}=???=\frac{1}{2}f''(x_0)$$
So my question is what should I do at $(???)$ ? I'm guessing that if I get this step figured out, finding the limit of $f(x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1})$ is analogous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write
$$
f\left( {x_1 } \right) = f\left( {x_0 } \right) + f'\left( {x_0 } \right)\left( {x_1  - x_0 } \right)
 + {1 \over 2}f''\left( {x_0 } \right)\left( {x_1  - x_0 } \right)^{\,2}  + O\left( {\left( {x_1  - x_0 } \right)^{\,3} } \right)
$$
and to keep the following passages more clear let's use the concise form
$$
f\left( {x_1 } \right) = f\left( {x_0 } \right) + f'\left( {x_0 } \right)\Delta x_0  + {1 \over 2}f''\left( {x_0 } \right)\Delta x_0 ^{\,2}  + O\left( {\Delta x_0 ^{\,3} } \right)
$$

Then  write $f(x_2)$ in this double version
$$
\eqalign{
  & f\left( {x_2 } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = f\left( {x_1 } \right) + f'\left( {x_1 } \right)\Delta x_1  + {1 \over 2}f''\left( {x_1 } \right)\Delta x_1 ^{\,2}  + O\left( {\Delta x_1 ^{\,3} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {f\left( {x_0 } \right) + f'\left( {x_0 } \right)\Delta x_0  + {1 \over 2}f''\left( {x_0 } \right)\Delta x_0 ^{\,2}  + O\left( {\Delta x_0 ^{\,3} } \right)} \right) +   \cr 
  &  + \left( {f'\left( {x_0 } \right) + f''\left( {x_0 } \right)\Delta x_0  + O\left( {\Delta x_0 ^{\,2} } \right)} \right)\Delta x_1  +   \cr 
  &  + {1 \over 2}\left( {f''\left( {x_0 } \right) + O\left( {\Delta x_0 } \right)} \right)\Delta x_1 ^{\,2}  + O\left( {\Delta x_1 ^{\,3} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = f\left( {x_0 } \right) + f'\left( {x_0 } \right)\left( {\Delta x_0  + \Delta x_1 } \right) + {1 \over 2}f''\left( {x_0 } \right)\Delta x_0 \left( {\Delta x_0  + \Delta x_1 } \right) +   \cr 
  &  + O\left( {\Delta x_0 ^{\,3} } \right) + O\left( {\Delta x_0 ^{\,2} \Delta x_1 } \right) + O\left( {\Delta x_0 \Delta x_1 ^{\,2} } \right) + O\left( {\Delta x_1 ^{\,3} } \right) \cr} 
$$

Therefore
$$
\eqalign{
  & f\left[ {x_0 ,x_1 } \right] = {{\left( {f\left( {x_1 } \right) - f\left( {x_0 } \right)} \right)} \over {\Delta x_0 }}
 = f'\left( {x_0 } \right) + {1 \over 2}f''\left( {x_0 } \right)\Delta x_0  + O\left( {\Delta x_0 ^{\,2} } \right)  \cr 
  & f\left[ {x_1 ,x_2 } \right] = {{\left( {f\left( {x_2 } \right) - f\left( {x_1 } \right)} \right)} \over {\Delta x_1 }}
 = f'\left( {x_1 } \right) + {1 \over 2}f''\left( {x_1 } \right)\Delta x_1  + O\left( {\Delta x_1 ^{\,2} } \right)  \cr 
  & f\left[ {x_0 ,x_1 ,x_2 } \right] = {{f\left[ {x_1 ,x_2 } \right] - f\left[ {x_0 ,x_1 } \right]} \over {\left( {x_2  - x_0 } \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {\left( {\Delta x_0  + \Delta x_1 } \right)}}\left( {f'\left( {x_1 } \right) - f'\left( {x_0 } \right)
 + {1 \over 2}f''\left( {x_1 } \right)\Delta x_1  - {1 \over 2}f''\left( {x_0 } \right)\Delta x_0 } \right) + O\left( {\Delta x} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {\left( {\Delta x_0  + \Delta x_1 } \right)}}\left( {f''\left( {x_0 } \right)\Delta x_0
  + {1 \over 2}f''\left( {x_0 } \right)\Delta x_1  + O\left( {\Delta x_0 \Delta x_1 } \right) - {1 \over 2}f''\left( {x_0 } \right)\Delta x_0 } \right) + O\left( {\Delta x} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 2}f''\left( {x_0 } \right) + O\left( {\Delta x} \right) \cr} 
$$

The "general principle" of the method is clear:
since you want the relation with the MacLaurin series at $x=x_0$ 
then we shall **tend** towards expressing $f^{(n)}(x_k)$ as a series around $x_0$.
I wrote "tend to" because we must do that in cascade, as it is
apparent above.
In fact,  $f\left[ {x_m ,x_{m+1}, \cdots, x_n } \right]$ implies the division by $(x_n-x_m)$, so we shall
develop first as series around the lowest point $x_m$, to simplify the divisor,
and then carry on developing around the lowest point that appears
in the denominator.

But that's not a practical way to go, either theoretical and computional-wise.

The theoretical demonstration can be achieved by the [Mean Value Theorem for divide differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem_%28divided_differences%29), which states
$$
f\left[ {x_0 , \cdots ,x_n } \right] = {1 \over {n!}}f^{\left( n \right)} \left( \xi  \right)\quad 
\left| {\;\min \left( {x_0 , \cdots ,x_n } \right) < \xi  < \max \left( {x_0 , \cdots ,x_n } \right)} \right.
$$
and which, to our purposes, we can write as
$$
f\left[ {x_0 , \cdots ,x_n } \right] = {1 \over {n!}}f^{\left( n \right)} \left( \xi  \right) = {1 \over {n!}}f^{\left( n \right)} \left( {x_0 } \right) + O\left( w \right)
$$
where $w$ is the length of the interval containing $x_0, \cdots x_n$.

Comment: Is $f[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ analogous? If yes, how is it possible to show a similar result for some $f[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ ?

Comment: @pls_halp: I "extended" my answer: hope it is helpful.

Comment: Not sure exactly how to do the theoretical demonstration?

Comment: @Mathguy  what explained in linked Wikipedia article is not enough ?